# Filter rows if array contains value in a given range

Tags: arrays, postgresql, range

I have a PostgreSQL table with a column `timeslot` which is an `int array`. I need to make a query that returns rows whose `timeslot` contains at least one number within a specified range. Alternatively, it could return rows whose `timeslot` contains values greater than 0. Right now, my query looks like this:

`SELECT * FROM shows WHERE timeslot @> ARRAY[167]`, which will only return items from `shows` whose `timeslot` contains 167, when what I really need is something like:

`SELECT * FROM shows WHERE timeslot @> 0-167`, or

`SELECT * FROM shows WHERE timeslot @> >0`

Comment: I think you need the array comparison expressions: [`ANY`/`ALL`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparisons.html#AEN19712), like: `0 < ANY(timeslot)`. But be aware, that these expressions usually don't use any index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the overlap operator `&&` together with an array instantiated us:

```
SELECT * 
FROM shows
WHERE timeslot && array(SELECT generate_series(0, 67))
```

The [`&& operator`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/intarray.html) returns true if and only if its two array arguments overlap.  The [`generate_series`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-srf.html) method creates a table with `INT` elements in a range, and the `array` initializer turns that table into an array so that it can be used with `&&`.

Comment: Ben Reich, could you please let me know how to order the results by their overlap? Thanks